# Коробка передач 9-ступінчаста чи 9-ступенева?

Tags: вибір-слова

Як правильно написати вираз "коробка передач 9-ступінчаста" чи "9-ступенева"?

Answer (score 1):

З СУМ-11

> **[Ступінчастий](http://sum.in.ua/s/stupinchastyj) 1.** Який складається із східців, уступів або має їх. *Представники від усіх народів Росії вітали промовця, який стояв на
>   ступінчастому підвищенні, з простягнутою вперед рукою* (Леонід Юхвід,
>   Оля, 1959, 208);  //  Який своїм виглядом нагадує сходи. *Усі
>   насторожено впилися очима в зелену ступінчасту стіну лісу, що поволі
>   на них насувалася* (Панас Кочура, Золота грамота, 1960, 105).
>    **2.** перен. Який відбувається, проводиться певними стадіями, етапами і т. ін. *І. В. Мічурін розробив.. метод ступінчастої акліматизації,
>   тобто метод поступового переносу рослин з півдня на північ* (Розвиток
>   науки в УРСР.., 1957, 357);
>
> **"Ступенева"** від слова **"ступінь"**
>   **[Ступінь](http://sum.in.ua/s/stupinj) 1.** Порівняльна величина, що характеризує розмір, інтенсивність чого-небудь.  *Словами холодний, теплий, гарячий ми характеризуємо різний ступінь нагрітості, різну температуру тіла* (Фізика, II, 1957, 7); //  Міра вияву чого-небудь.

**[Коробки передач](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87)** класифікуються за способом перемикання **ступенів**, за кількістю **ступенів** свободи

***Отже, правильно "коробка передач 9-ступенева".***